# Why is The Flash not deaf, given the sonic booms created by his speed should have hurt his hearing?

Tags: dc, the-flash

When an object travels in fast speed, it creates a sonic boom. Frequent exposure will cause deafness. Why isn't The Flash deaf as a result?

Comment: You must wonder why the pilots of supersonic airplanes are not all deaf.

Comment: @user14111 That question belongs on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions). It is off topic here.

Comment: @MrLister - Then so is this question, as the answers should, logically, be the same.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You must be missing the subtle difference between a man who can run faster than the speed of sound and a ditto plane.

Comment: Nananananana Speed Force! Speed Force! Speed Force, Speed Force, Speed Force.

Comment: How to delete this question? From the number of downvotes, it seems like some people are offended. I wonder what is wrong with the question. Can the people who downvoted explain?

Comment: I also don’t understand the downvotes. It’s a valid question. Pilots fly inside a plane with a helmet and headphones. There’s nothing that justifies this number of downvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities) has super-healing.  If his hearing was damaged, he'd heal from it.

He also has the Speed Force, which protects him from various side effects of his speed.

Quoting from the above link:

> Speedsters can also heal more rapidly than an average human. In addition, most incarnations have an invisible aura around their respective bodies that protects them from air friction and the kinetic effects of their powers.

In other words, he has (effectively magical) protection from the side effects of his powers.  And if he didn't, he has accelerated healing to recover from such damage.

Comment: As always a canonical source is preferred to fan speculation. The above speculation can be found all over the internet, but I've yet to find a credible source be quoted.

Comment: @Edlothiad, the rapid healing has been shown, in comics and on TV. The protective aura was introduced in the Silver Age comics and has been a staple since then. What other canon do you need?

Comment: @KeithMorrison Examples in the post. I'm not calling the entirety of the internet liars, although a credible source removes all doubt. Proof of such "protective aura" in the post takes it a long way. From speculation based on trust to canonically supported claims.

Comment: Every "this doesn't make much sense" question about Flash's speed's answer is just "Speed Force."

Comment: @starpilotsix iknowrite?!  It's almost like someone somewhere along the line just *invented* "Speed Force" to make the nerds shut up about it.

Answer (score 3):

Same reason why pilots of supersonic aircraft aren't deaf. He is inside the protective shockcone generated by his nose (nose-cone in the case of aircraft).
While in this cone, his ears are out of the airflow and the shockwave (which generates the boom) is radiating away from him. This is subject to his speed, so at Mach1 the shockcone may not encompass his ears, and he would get the boom. Does a sonic boom generated by your own nose hurt? You would have to stick your head into a 700mph airstream to figure that out. Since that is potentially lethal, some canon suggests "Speed Force" protects the Flash. This is the same concept as inertial damping fields used in science fiction. You can dampen the inertia, but anything moving through air above Mach1 generates a shockwave. Get hit by that wave and your ears interpret it as a sonic boom.

Comment: Pilots don't hear the sound because they are outside the airflow. Essentially they are inside the shockcone that projects from the nose of the aircraft. If the Flash runs normally, then his nose would start a shockwave, that should envelop his head. This protective envelope only works at speed because the shockwave is pulled into a cone. So  yes, technically not outrunning the sound, just pulling the circular shockwave into a cone.

Answer (score 2):

Well,  the flash doesn't produce sonic Shockwaves.

Proof? Take a gander at the glass windows he superspeeds by that do not shatter.